# SSAS usage based optmisation

Tags: ssas

I have one question regarding Usage based optimization in ssas,
 I have set up an usage based optimization in SSAS, and deployed and processed for aggregation. Just want to know, whether the next scheduled SSAS cube process will consider the SSAS query log? Or it will consider only when I deploy next time?

Answer (score 5):

After you designed aggregations based on usage logs, its solid - aggregation schema is created during that process and won't change unless you manually redeisgn them again.